# Dynamic addition & use of variable outside for loop- Selenium

Tags: java, loops, selenium, automation

Below is the scenario i am trying to automate:
Put all numerical values of the links in a Selenium Weblist & perform an addition and later to verify if the sum of count matches a fixed number.

The issue is that the numerical links returns a number engulfed in braces example:(20)(35)(16)(15)

I need to first trim these brackets & fetch only the numbers & then perform the addition i.e: 20+35+16+15

Later i need to assert the total against the number i.e: Assert.assertequals(sum,'86')

```
 List<WebElement> lists=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.ndocs"));
        for (int i=0; i<lists.size(); ){

            String trimmed_value=lists.get(i).getText();
            trimmed_value=lists.get(i).getText().trim().substring(trimmed_value.indexOf("(") + 1);
            trimmed_value=lists.get(i).getText().trim().substring(0, trimmed_value.indexOf(")"));
            System.out.println(trimmed_value);
            int numerical_value = Integer.parseInt(trimmed_value);
            i++;
        }
```

Till now i am able to get the elements, iterate them & able to remove the braces & get the numbers, I am stuck upon how to perform the addition operation & then do an Assert for the count.
Any help will be much appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code.

Initialize a variable outside the method and add every trimmed_value to it as explained below.

import assertEquals(import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;)

```
int expected_value=86;
int numerical_value=0;
List<WebElement> lists = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.ndocs"));

  for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); ) {
            String trimmed_value = lists.get(i).getText();
            trimmed_value = lists.get(i).getText().trim().substring(trimmed_value.indexOf("(") + 1);
            trimmed_value = lists.get(i).getText().trim().substring(0, trimmed_value.indexOf(")"));
            System.out.println(trimmed_value);
            numerical_value =numerical_value+Integer.parseInt(trimmed_value);
            i++;
        }
assertEquals(expected_value, numerical_value);
```